# When using ArgoCD, any modification to initContainer do not update on the pod

Tags: argocd

I have a question regarding ArgoCD. When using `argocd app sync` to deploy our helm charts, we have a weird issue which we have to do this manually for changes to `initContainers`. The scenario is like this:

- We make a change to a `Deployment` service to remove `initContainer` or edit the `initContainer`.
- If we are to use `helm upgrade --install`, it works as intended; however, when using `argocd app sync`, the modifications do not occur on the pods that were updated.
- The manual process is for me to go into the `Deployment` and remove the change of what was to occur.

I am sure this is a simple thing on my side but I would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please bring the --reset-values parameter, otherwise it will use the values of the previous version, eg: helm upgrade --install --reset-values
When helm upgrade, --reuse-values is used by default. For the explanation of these two parameters, you can view the help document

```
--reset-values                               when upgrading, reset the values to the ones built into the chart
--reuse-values                               when upgrading, reuse the last release's values and merge in any overrides from the command line via --set and -f. If '--reset-values' is specified, this is ignored
```